# Stop this weird jQuery Glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

My question is how do i fix this weird glitch in jquery.

When i move one of the boxes it makes all the other boxes shoot downwards and im not sure why its happening. does anyone know whats causing this problem?

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fsVd/273/) has all my code on it

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){
            $('#container').sortable({
                connectWith: "#container",
            cursor: "move"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
});
```

The HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="container-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="container-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="container-item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
lists {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#container {
    background: lightgrey;
    width:500px;
    height: 50px;
}
.container-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  max-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What I'm seeing is the behaviour I'd expect to see...

Comment: I'm not having any problems with the code given - what browser are you using?

Comment: @thebluefox well youre not really helping with that comment, i want to stop this behaviour.

Comment: @VaLLe. Im using chrome, its not pushing the other divs to the bottom of the page?

Comment: No divs are being pushed using FF 50

Comment: @YasminFrench For me it shows the expected behaviour like thebluefox said. I'm using Chrome 55.0.2883.87

Comment: @Alfabravo please, look again ive updated the question

Comment: @YasminFrench Clearly you weren't helping my not giving us the right link...

Comment: @YasminFrench to rephrase Bluefox's comment, it seems like everything works as expected to me too.  Maybe you could elaborate on what you want to happen?

Comment: @Ben Ive updated the question i was at fault

Comment: @VaLLe. Please check the updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `float: left` to `.container-item`.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3fsVd/274/)